# Sql "where" to compare array of dates - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, date, psql

I have a db table `events`, it has a column `dates` which stores arrays of dates like this

```
eg: ["2017-05-19","2018-04-19","2005-04-19","2017-06-19","2015-04-9"]
```

say im given month value, `05`. I should compare months of dates present in `dates` column for each event and return list of all events where it has dates containing month exactly `05`.
**so, if event1 and event2 has month 05 in array of dates, return event1 and event2.**

> I tried this, got confused. `where("dates @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", don't_know_what_to_give_here)`

Comment: On phone so can only give comment.  If no one responds I'l do a full answer later.  Basically, you need to use the strptime method to convert your string dates to actual dates and then you can check for matching months.  Strptime doc here: (https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class)

Comment: thank you for reply, yes we should use strptime and then compare.. but we should go through all dates in given array for an event, and check for all the events in similar way. but im still in confusion in doing so.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into making a separate event_dates table with each event having many dates etc. in the future.  But for this scenario, you can treat psql arrays like any other collection of arrays thanks to active record.  However, you don't want to instantiate every object and loop over every event in your table just to check dates.  Therefore I'd recommend using 'pluck' to grab all dates & the records id so you can use a regex to scan the dates array and then add the corresponding id to its own array.  Then load the arrays of id's: @events = Event.where(id: [ids_with_matching_months])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but you can use the postgres [`array_to_string`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html) method and then the `LIKE` operator on the resulting string.

```
select *
from your_table_name
where array_to_string(dates, ',') LIKE '%-05-%'
```

With Rails

```
Model.where("array_to_string(dates, ',') LIKE '%-?-%'", month)
# just make sure month has a leading zero e.g. 01 instead of just 1
```

Comment: cool, but what if i save array in dates format instead of string.
eg: `[Tue, 04 Apr 2017, Tue, 11 Apr 2017, Tue, 18 Apr 2017, Tue, 25 Apr 2017, Tue, 02 May 2017, Tue, 09 May 2017]`, where each element of array is of class `date` and not string.

Comment: Just do a LIKE on the month name then.

Comment: okay, but what if i want to return events when  date is greater than > today?

Comment: If you need that you will really have to rethink your database schema. I just made an answer to your specific question, not all possible scenarios. Splitting the dates into a separate table is the only real solution.